# .aux not backed up, how to force rebuild?

Tags: auxiliary-files, texlipse

Eclipse/Texlipse puts a bunch of files in a sub-folder `/tmp`.
I did not back those up as the folder name `/tmp` gave me the impression those can be easily rebuild from the `.tex` and `.bib` file.
Now I recover from the backup and and neither "Force build" nor "Run BibTeX on next build" do the trick.
I get the Error `File not found: /project/tmp/file.aux.`

How to recreate the `.aux` file?
And what is it?
Why does it live in `/tmp` if it is essential for building?

Comment: You can compile from the command line if TeXlipse isn't cooperative. As described, it is surely a bug. In some cases, the only way to recover from an error is to delete such files and compile again from scratch. So any editor which refuses to run the compilation without them is necessarily flawed. I don't know why an editor would even keep track of them. TeX does a perfectly good job on its own.

Comment: Just a note for the future: I edited out the answer from your question.  We like to keep these two concepts separate on the site; it's this standardization and subsequent familiarity that makes StackExchange so useful for a variety of topics.  Thanks, and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how is someone who has the same issue being helped now? The answer is now hidden in my comment for the first answer.

Comment: @MaxN This is why everyone is able to edit (or at least suggest edits) to both questions and answers :) It's a community effort to help the community.  For example, see the edit I added to yours for the answer below.

Comment: So is it okay to change Bernhard's answer so it truly answers the question? I think I suddenly have the rights to edit it.

Comment: @MaxN Do you want to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21210/comment-discussion)?

Comment: @MaxN Or we could discuss in the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) – doesn't look like a whole lot of people are there right now, so we wouldn't be intruding.  Back-and-forth comments just aren't a great way to have a conversation :)

Comment: @MaxN Ah – sorry :( You won't be able to join chat until you get another five reputation.  Privileges like this are detailed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) – they're in place to keep the site sane (safe from bots, etc.)  Read that page carefully – it has all the information you really need (along with the welcome link, of course) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.aux` file  contains data from compilation, and it is used by LaTeX itself on subsequent compilation to resolve all cross-references, by BibTeX or biber to build bibliographies, etc.

I suppose it's in `./tmp` (as do many editors) to prevent the main file directories from being full of dozens of those auxiliary files. LaTeX, *a priori*, knows where to find them.

To rebuild it, just `Project > Clean...` and recompile.

Comment: After some more searching around in Eclipse/texlipse I found it. It is called "Clean..." in the "Project" menu. That does the trick! Recompiling without that always fails.